# Minimal implementation of function with conditional type return type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types, conditional-statements

The TypeScript handbook offers the following example of using conditional types rather than function overloading:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html

```js
interface IdLabel {
  id: number /* some fields */;
}

interface NameLabel {
  name: string /* other fields */;
}

type NameOrId<T extends number | string> = T extends number
  ? IdLabel
  : NameLabel;


function createLabel<T extends number | string>(idOrName: T): NameOrId<T> {
  throw "unimplemented";
}

let a = createLabel("typescript");
//  ^ = let a: NameLabel

let b = createLabel(2.8);
//  ^ = let b: IdLabel

let c = createLabel(Math.random() ? "hello" : 42);
//  ^ = let c: NameLabel | IdLabel
```

However, the Handbooks doesn't provide an actual implementation for the function. I've tried to implement the function as follows ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBMAycBGEA2yA3gFDLLDoBcyIArgLZ5TID0AVMgM4D2DKMYAXRdk7VgG4SAXxKhIsRCgBycftjyFS5EGog0uYKKADmbTjzAALaMkHDR4qbLABPAA4q9AeSgYAPAAqyBAAHpAgIrSMzMgAPtxGpgB8yAC8yMFhEVH0TNBkyAD8aFi4BIU0qurl+FIkMHQgCGDAPCDICFAQcJAaBEEh4RCRonmxCYbGICbJABSUvtX6mQCUVT5+6EGp2hQwyHNunjwHi1DL6WkZAOTj0DeryN1gdFAdRBTUX0t6yNJScgvN4fXT8GjnS4AmQkEj4CBgZBwdKdbq9CD9fBzABExwgXC6wHcYGxqykrFY5AAekVYfDETgUV0en1anMAEwAOgAHGSSBTqbS4QjOky0azNHMALK9KycqBwSJ8OZPErYmz4fA8bHIGgAFnZfIFyBpQA)):

```js
function createLabel<T extends number | string>(idOrName: T): NameOrId<T> {
  if (typeof idOrName === 'number') {
    return { id: idOrName };
  }
  return { name: idOrName };
          // ^ Type '{ name: T; }' is not assignable to type 'NameOrId<T>'.(2322)
}
```

which results in a compiler error, so apparently TypeScript's type-narrowing can't resolve this. What additional information do I need to provide the compiler for a valid implementation? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is currently a limitation of TypeScript.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) for a feature request to improve this.

The compiler is not particularly adept when reasoning about *unspecified generic types*, especially when the type is a conditional type.  A type like `NameOrId<T>`, where `T` is not a specific type (such as the generic type parameter `T` inside the implementation of `createLabel()`) is more or less opaque to the compiler.  It *defers* evaluating the type until the generic type parameters it depends on are specified.  Until then, it cannot really verify that any specific type is assignable to it.

So all you get are these errors.  For now there are only workarounds.

---

When the compiler is unable to verify that some expression is assignable to some type, but you are sure of it, you can use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to just *tell* the compiler of your certainty.  Type assertions will allow you to treat an expression `x` that the compiler sees as type `X` `as` an expression of type `Y` (`x as Y`), as long as the compiler thinks `X` and `Y` are sufficiently related.  When it doesn't think so, you can usually force this to happen with an intermediate assertion related to both `X` and `Y` (such as `x as any as Y` or `x as unknown as Y`.

For `createLabel()` this could look like the following:

```
function createLabel<T extends number | string>(idOrName: T): NameOrId<T> {
  if (typeof idOrName === 'number') return { id: idOrName as number } as NameOrId<T>;
  return { name: idOrName as string } as NameOrId<T>;
}
```

---

Another workaround is to continue using [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads), which allow for the separation between a function's *call signature* (possibly multiple of these) and its *implementation signature*. The compiler is fairly loose when checking the implementation signature against the call signatures, which tends to give a developer similar leeway as with type assertions, without having to write `as Y` all over the place.  It has the same issue with type safety though, so when you do this you are essentially taking some of the responsibility for verifying safety away from the compiler.

In your case we have just the one call signature, a generic call signature whose return type is a conditional type.  And for the implementation signature, we can widen `T` to the associated constraint, `string | number`:

```
function createLabel<T extends number | string>(idOrName: T): NameOrId<T>;
function createLabel(idOrName: number | string): NameOrId<number | string> {
  if (typeof idOrName === 'number') return { id: idOrName };
  return { name: idOrName };
}
```

The compiler is happy because it sees the implementation return type as `IdLabel | NameLabel`, which while not verifiably assignable to `NameOrId<T>`, is similar enough for the overload to be considered compatible.

---

Just to hammer the point home: this is a workaround.  The compiler can't verify what you're doing exactly.  You will be prevented from doing something totally bonkers like

```
function createLabelBonkers<T extends number | string>(idOrName: T): NameOrId<T> {
  return new Date() as NameOrId<T>; // error
  // Conversion of type 'Date' to type 'NameOrId<T>' may be a mistake
}

function createLabelBonkers2<T extends number | string>(idOrName: T): NameOrId<T>;
function createLabelBonkers2(idOrName: number | string): NameOrId<number | string> {
  return new Date(); // error, not assignable to NameLabel | IdLabel
}
```

but if you make mistakes where the types involved are related to the correct ones, the compiler will not and cannot warn you:

```
function createLabelBad<T extends number | string>(idOrName: T): NameOrId<T> {
  return (Math.random() < 0.5 ? { id: 123 } : { name: "abc" }) as NameOrId<T>
}

function createLabelBad2<T extends number | string>(idOrName: T): NameOrId<T>;
function createLabelBad2(idOrName: number | string): NameOrId<number | string> {
  return Math.random() < 0.5 ? { id: 123 } : { name: "abc" };
}
```

It doesn't see the difference between the implementations of `createLabel()` and `createLabelBad()`.  In neither case can it detect if the implementations are correct or not; the burden of doing this is on you, so be careful.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBMAycBGEA2yA3gFDLLDoBcyIArgLZ5TID0AVMgM4D2DKMYAXRdk7VgG4SAXxKhIsRCgBycftjyFS5EGog0uYKKADmbTjzAALaMkHDR4qbLABPAA4q9AeSgYAPAAqyBAAHpAgIrSMzMgAPtxGpgB8yAC8yMFhEVH0TNBkyAD8aFi4BIU0qurl+FIkMHQgCGDAPCDICFAQcJAaBEEh4RCRonmxCYbGICbJABSUvtX6mQCUVT5+6EGp2hQwyHNunjwHi1DL6WkZAOTj0DeryN1gdFAdRBTUX0t6yHBjGK2aT-UTLXwBQLJKTkF5vD60PQ0c6XAGJaZmEFo8FbHbOEgNJotNodLo9Pq1ABMg2yI1yQJYkySM3mKKRaw2-Ah2yhUkazVa7U63V6EH6+EpC3Qv34NHujPRpnWyBxAXl8UVLOIhWAByOHggpx+Fz+11u8sezwgr3exC+yOlJv4yGkMKtNoRullxsurpkBPw1v+6WF5LFtTmACJjhAuF1gO4wJHVlJWKxyAA9IoBoM4ENk0XiuaUgB0AA4UyQ05nsyRA2BOvmRRTNHMALK9KwlqBwSJ8OZPEqRmz4fA8SPIGgAFkpleryCzBMJApJocLtQAQu0ANbQLg04ajaL5BVTFJSmUrQLK1U83aFOG2kAQADuyAAIqKB6CVZtIdC2HTaAoB4KBCmrABhdoADc91XI0Y2QG5P0gG5kDAHh0INJDbx2NCGDgVxkDwYMGGAQw4F3f1l2JIUCxbAgtxAXcoC4akskPekTw1M8WQvJ0rxvP87z5IlBVJZtw00JiWLY-jljlBkeOZEwhK5XF1SZDF71ha14VoV8Py-FNAJCKAQKgAAaWhLFBLhgBMXQcEDdDMOWcUNQwcVqJo8S1wY-ANzgHkhhyQFuK0882W9a9OQgbkdm1XSPUODtrG7Xt0H7J5-GQAAGEsAFZijtSgaAARkpABmF1JztL0VkjXAEAnaQnmxYSdmo-laIksNxSC9B2NCulwomTVZnk9lYt-dT-1Elc6MkgbgslaKVk0ia1PijSlMirU9kfDo0q7Hs+wYb9coK4qSk+MrkEqmqQRoT4GpoJqcBal18SAA)

Comment: Ah! Thank you for the in-depth clarification & suggestion of workarounds for the moment.