# Generic function returns different output type depending on generic

Tags: typescript

The typing of the function below is working as required.  But I'm forcing it via `as` - which in general should be avoided.  In this case, is my approach acceptable, or is there a better approach that avoids `as` I'm not aware of?

```js
function fn<
    S = never
>(start?:S) {
    type RV = [S] extends [never] ?  { start<T>(arg:T): void } : void
    if(!start){
        return { start<T>(arg:T){ console.log(arg) } } as RV
    }
    console.log(start)
    return undefined as RV
}

const x1 = fn()    // { start<T>(arg: T): void;}
const x2 = fn('a') // void
```

[code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMMAeAsAKETxBlRAXkTAFMA3UgJywD4AKAZygEMqoB+ALjwEpEA3llyIoATwAOpRACUAakUQBtPAF1EpAB5RSYACaNlZSlXUccAxMzZRUAFQZsA5lzu8uicnBh7EAX0QPLx9hXFCcGGB6AEJrdl4hbBFcKlIoECokSzjbB3pnVwTECARGOAAbUgA6crgnfKonfgCAlkN5cP9OkrAyypq6plZ4ztT0zMRwPVJgGDJfNtk5LD8sLB7mRE0ARkUUen5cAHojwSth3MdGjzcg7z0AblXMDagtgCY9sHoAchYf-gnTz3IA)

Comment: Assigning the result of calling a function with a return type of `void` doesn't really make any sense. Do you mean `undefined` instead?

Comment: @Jared Smith, I don't understand your question - please clarify.  In this example if `start` is supplied, then `void` is returned.  If `start` is not supplied then an object is returned which enables one to later supply `start`.  I.e. depending on the generic `S` - the return type is different.

Comment: In types `void` means "I don't care about and won't ever use the return value". Here, you have a function that *might* return a value, which means you have to capture the return value and check. So semantically the correct type would be `Whatever | undefined`. Type `void` is for things where it isn't even possible to capture or care about the result, e.g. a callback passed to `.addEventListener`.

Comment: I'd say this is a current TS limitation where [ms/TS#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) is the relevant feature request to support it.  Does that address the question fully or am I missing something?

Comment: @Jared Smith, if `start` is supplied, then "I don't care about and won't ever use the return value" - i.e. the return type is `void`.  However if `start` is not supplied, then I do care about the return type.

Comment: @jcalz - thank you for that link which appears to be the exact same requirement.  So based on that, I'd say it's fair to assume the `as` is the only solution for now.

Comment: No problem.  See [the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66552211/2887218) and its answer for more information.